# make an user with different courses and display it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, backend

I want to know if exists a way to create an user with differents course that are already registered in his account and show it with links in his page, like:

User {user_name}

courses:

• link_to course1

• link_to course2

• link_to course3

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question and these are difficult to answer concisely and that makes them off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what you have

```
class User < ApplicatonRecord
  has_many :courses
end
```

and in controller you assign @user var.
You should have in view smth like that:

```
<p> User: <%= @user.name %> </p>
<ul>
<% @user.courses do |course| %>
  <li><%= link_to(course.name, course) %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```